# Ant table problem using both expandable and rowSelection

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want row selection checkbox to come first, if I use both expandable and rowSelection

But I am getting expandable as first column.

```
 <Table
  className='assignment-table'
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  pagination={false}
  expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
  rowSelection={
    props.onSelectionChange && {
      selectedRowKeys: props.selectedRows,
      onChange: props.onSelectionChange,
    }
  }
/>
```

How can we change row selection should come first here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dynamic-settings-antd-5-12-7-hgz4r7?file=%2Fdemo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this passing first two columns as below

```
   const columns = [
       Table.SELECTION_COLUMN,
       Table.EXPAND_COLUMN, ...]
```